# comment the <xref> tag and keep the text as plain, if section/@id is not matched with in folder xml or outside folder xml file

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, saxon, dtd, xslt-3.0

We want to comment the `<xref>` tags if `section/@id` is not matched in the same folder xml files or other folder xml files:

Each folder have multiple/single xml files and `<xref>` and `section/@id` tags will be in the all xml files

1. This `<xref href="aag-dep1_1.01">some text here</xref>` tag in the `"aat-fti"` folder but section in the `eat-rw` folder, if matched both `xref/@href` and `section/@id` then keep value `xref` tag as it is, it not matched then comment the `xref` tags keep the text as plain.

Please help and suggest, Thanks

See the below folder structure in screenshot, each folder have xml files but `xref/@href` and `sectin/@id` any xml files pr with in documents:
[image: folder structure from input]

**Input xml with `section/@id` in the `aa-fti` folder**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book id="book_id">
    <title>Generally Accepted Accounting Principles</title>
    <chapter id="chapter_id" role="ls_level_2">
        <chapterinfo>
            <titleabbrev>Chapter_abb</titleabbrev>
            <title>Chapter_title</title>
        </chapterinfo>
        <section id="aag-dep1_01">
            <para>text here</para>
            <para>text here</para>
            <para>containing auditing <xref href="fir_56_10">some text here</xref> guidance related to generally accepted auditing standard</para>
            <para> the effective dates for FASB ASU No. 2018 <xref href="aag-dep1_1.01">some text here</xref></para>
            <section id="aag-dep1_1.01">
                <para>text here <xref href="fot_79_ut">some text here</xref></para>
                <para>text here</para>
                <para>text here<xref href="aag-dep1_01">some text here</xref></para>
            </section>
            <section id="aag-dep1_2.01">
                <para>text here</para>
                <para>text here</para>
                <para>text here <xref href="aag-dep1_02">some text here</xref></para>
            </section>
        </section>
        <section id="aag-dep1_02">
            <para>text here</para>
            <para>text here</para>
            <para>ces, including engagements for entities in specia</para>
            <para>example, a large calendar-year public insurance en</para>
            <section id="aag-dep1_1.02">
                <para>text here</para>
                <para>text here</para>
                <para>text here <xref href="tih52_23">some text here</xref></para>
            </section>
        </section>
        <section id="aag-dep1_regulation_and_oversight">
            <para>text <xref href="aag-dep1_1.02">some text here</xref> here</para>
            <para>text here</para>
            <para>early application may do so as of the beginning</para>
            <para>Other auditing publications have no authoritative status;</para>
            <section id="aag-dep1_08">
                <para>text here <xref href="aag-dep1_regulation_and_oversight">some text here</xref></para>
                <para>text <xref href="nov1_22">some text here</xref> here</para>
                <para>text here</para>
            </section>
        </section>
    </chapter>
</book>
```

**Input xml file with `xref/@href` in the `eat-rw` folder**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book id="book_id">
    <title>Generally Accepted Accounting Principles</title>
    <chapter id="chapter_id" role="ls_level_2">
        <chapterinfo>
            <titleabbrev>Chapter_abb</titleabbrev>
            <title>Chapter_title</title>
        </chapterinfo>
        <section id="aag-dep1_01">
            <para>text here</para>
            <para>text here</para>
            <para>containing auditing <!--<xref href="fir_56_10">-->some text here<!--</xref>--> guidance related to generally accepted auditing standard</para>
            <para> the effective dates for FASB ASU No. 2018 <xref href="aag-dep1_1.01">some text here</xref></para>
            <section id="aag-dep1_1.01">
                <para>text <!--<xref href="fot_79_ut">-->some text here<!--</xref>--> here</para>
                <para>text here</para>
                <para>text here<xref href="aag-dep1_01">some text here</xref></para>
            </section>
            <section id="aag-dep1_2.01">
                <para>text here</para>
                <para>text here</para>
                <para>text here <xref href="aag-dep1_02">some text here</xref></para>
            </section>
        </section>
        <section id="aag-dep1_02">
            <para>text here</para>
            <para>text here</para>
            <para>ces, including engagements for entities in specia</para>
            <para>example, a large calendar-year public insurance en</para>
            <section id="aag-dep1_1.02">
                <para>text here</para>
                <para>text here</para>
                <para>text here <!--<xref href="tih52_23">-->some text here<!--</xref>--></para>
            </section>
        </section>
        <section id="aag-dep1_regulation_and_oversight">
            <para>text <xref href="aag-dep1_1.02">some text here</xref> here</para>
            <para>text here</para>
            <para>early application may do so as of the beginning</para>
            <para>Other auditing publications have no authoritative status;</para>
            <section id="aag-dep1_08">
                <para>text here <xref href="aag-dep1_regulation_and_oversight">some text here</xref></para>
                <para>text <!--<xref href="nov1_22">-->some text here<!--</xref>--> here</para>
                <para>text here</para>
            </section>
        </section>
    </chapter>
</book>
```

Comment: Now xslt 1.0? Previous question about same issue was 2.0.

Comment: This is xslt 2.0, and yes this is the same issue we asked in last question but in this scenario all xml files are in each folder and they can be cross reference in any folder if "xref/@href" is not found with "section/@id" value of any folder then that "xref" tag has to be commented and the text has to be kept plain. Please see the screenshot above and help me

Comment: @MartinHonnen can you look above question? It is hamble request

Comment: XSLT 2 or higher? Which XSLT 2 (or higher) processor exactly do you use? Saxon (Java, .NET, C/C++) allows you to process collections of XML files using its default collection URI resolver so that would give us a tool to tackle this. But if you use Altova things might need different code.

Comment: Thanks @MartinHonnen, I am using Oxygen Editor (Saxon PE 9.9.1.7)

Answer (score 1):

Using XSLT 3 with Saxon 9.9, if you put the following XSLT in the parent folder of all the subfolders you have shown, it processes all `*.xml` files recursively and writes the transformed result to e.g. `subfoldername-output`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:param name="collection-uri" select="'?select=*.xml;recurse=yes'"/>
  
  <xsl:param name="collection-docs" select="collection($collection-uri)"/>
  
  <xsl:key name="section" match="section" use="@id"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$collection-docs"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="result-uri" select="let $uri-tokens := tokenize(base-uri(), '/') return string-join(($uri-tokens[position() lt last() - 1], $uri-tokens[last() - 1] || '-output', $uri-tokens[last()]), '/')"/>
    <xsl:result-document href="{$result-uri}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="xref[not(some $doc in $collection-docs satisfies key('section', @href, $doc))]">
    <xsl:comment>&lt;xref href="<xsl:value-of select="@href"/>"&gt;</xsl:comment><xsl:apply-templates/><xsl:comment>&lt;/xref&gt;</xsl:comment>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Start the processing with the initial template and no input file. I think the approach should work with a simple folder structure (e.g. the parent folder with the XSLT contains one level of different subfolders with XML documents to be processed) but make sure you test that carefully on some test sample data before using it on your full folder set.

Comment: Thanks @Martin, I will try and Shall we use xslt 2.0?

Comment: Saxon 9.9 is an XSLT 3 processor so I would suggest to use `version="3.0"` in the XSLT code.

Comment: Okay, I will try and let you know